# How do I set my application property in a composed task?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a composed task with the following definition:

`task create my-task --definition "taskA && taskB"`

I would like to set an application property for **taskA** when I launch the task and pass a value that has spaces in it.  As well, I need to set the Spring active profile for each of the child tasks.

My Java code for the application properties in **TaskA** is as such:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "taskA")
public class TaskAProperties {
  private String name;
  ... setter and getter
}
```

I've tried a number of commands but can't get it to work with spaces.

`task launch my-task --arguments "--composed-task-arguments=--spring.profiles.active=local --composed-task-properties=app.taskA.name='Bill Gates'"`

When I print out the **name** property, it's null;

Answer (score 0):

In example above I would use properties instead of command line args.  Using the shell it would look something like:
`task launch my-task --properties "app.my-task.taskA.spring.profiles.active=local,app.my-task.taskA.taska.name=Bill Gates"` . More can be read about it [here](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/feature-guides/batch/composed-task/#passing-properties-to-tasks-in-the-graph).

One issue I see in your example is the use of `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "taskA")`.   The use of taskA as a prefix is incorrect, you should get an error in your app stating something like  `Modify 'taskA' so that it conforms to the canonical names requirements.`